# Uploading an in-memory file to Skydrive in a windows store app?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, stream, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I've got the following Windows Phone 8 code to upload a file to Skydrive. The file is a collection of SQLite objects serialized to XML

```
XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings(); 
xmlWriterSettings.Indent = true; 
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<MyObject>));                
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{       
    using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(ms, xmlWriterSettings))
    {
        xs.Serialize(xmlWriter, MyObject);
    }
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); 
    result = await App.LiveConnectClient.UploadAsync("me/skydrive", "sync.xml", ms, OverwriteOption.Overwrite);
}
```

I'm trying to port this code to a c# Windows Store app, but I've come up against a problem. Under the windows store version of the Live SDK, UploadAsync is not available. BackgroundUploadAsync is the closes thing, and it only accepts `Windows.Storage.Streams.IInputStream`. I can't directly create `IInputStream` like I can with 'MemoryStream' in the code above.

All the examples I've found online detail how to upload a file from isolatedStorage. I don't want to have to write the file to isolatedStorage just to be able to upload it.

Can someone share some code for uploading a stream? Failing that, does anyone have a method to convert `MemoryStream` to `Windows.Storage.Streams.IInputStream`

Comment: Have you tried implementing the interface? Probably so, but just asking. It often becomes clear what to do when you see the implemented members.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [InMemoryRandomAccessStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.inmemoryrandomaccessstream), which is the replacement in WinRT for `MemoryStream` (though `MemoryStream` still exists).

They provide some neat extensions for it in `System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime`.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;

XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings(); 
xmlWriterSettings.Indent = true; 
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<MyObject>));                
using (InMemoryRandomAccessStream ms = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
{       
    using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(ms.AsStream(), xmlWriterSettings))
    {
        xs.Serialize(xmlWriter, MyObject);
    }
    ms.Seek(0); 
    result = await App.LiveConnectClient.UploadAsync("me/skydrive", "sync.xml", ms.GetInputStreamAt(0), OverwriteOption.Overwrite);
}
```

Should work. Hope this helps and Happy Coding!